# Mixing Box2D Accelerometer + Gravity?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, box2d, gravity

I have 2 questions:
1. Is it possible to retrieve the current X Coordinate of a b2Body? I know the API GetPosition but that is not specific enough, I need the X coordinate specifically.
2. Is it possible to add gravity to my specific b2Body in my UIAccelerometer delegate method?

What I am trying to do is move the b2Body with the current UIAccelerometer input with Box2D gravity in one line using Apply Force.
This is what I have so far, doesn't anyone know how I can incorporate #1+#2 into this line?:

```
body->ApplyForce(b2Vec2(accelX*100, -30.0f), body->GetPosition());
```

Thanks!

Edit1: 
Thanks for answering those questions, that cleared it up for me!
This leaves me 3 more questions:
**1**. Now that I understand how to get the x coordinate of b2Body, how would I set it?
Would it be something like this?

```
body->GetPosition().x = 30;
```

**2**. With these x coordinates it is the same X coordinate as if I was using UIKit correct? I know UIKit frames things different I just want to make sure that if I did something similar in UIKit, it would output the same X coordinate, is that correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Answer to 1)**

```
b2Vec pos = body->GetPosition();
float x = pos.x;
// do whatever you need to do with x
```

You can also write

```
float x = body->GetPosition().x;
```

**Answer to 2)**

Store whatever values you need from the UIAccelerometer didAccelerate method in an instance variable. For example accelX:

```
accelX = acceleration.x;
```

In your world update method simply use those values to calculate the force in whatever way you need it. Then apply the force like you posted:

```
body->ApplyForce(b2Vec2(accelX*100, -30.0f), body->GetPosition());
```

Answer (score 2):

1) 1) body->GetPosition().x

1) 2) Either apply a force or change the world's gravity.

2) 1) You use SetPosition(b2Vec2).

2) 2) Box2d coordinates are divided by PTM_RATIO and 0,0 is in the bottom left for box2d, but top left for UIKit.

Comment: So if I want to retrieve the X coordinate UIKit style but using Box2D I would have to divide the X coordinate by the PTM Ratio?
Also would this be the same for 2.1?